# Why most keras examples use shape=(None,) instead of shape=(None)?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, numpy

I'm reading several keras tutorials and found that many examples are written like this:

`keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="english")`

Why do they use `shape=(None,)` instead of just `shape=(None)`?

I know that here `None` means any value. But, why are they writing that extra comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keras expects the shape argument to be tuple. And in python if you write `shape =(None)` and check its datatype with `type(shape)` you will get the output as `int`. However, if you write `shape=(None,)`, it's considered as a tuple containing one element which is `None`.

So basically, the extra comma is used to define a tuple with one element.